# Are PHP Namespaces dependent on path of file?

Tags: php, yii2, namespaces, httpclient

In YII2 Framework
Path of File is root\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-httpclient\Client.php

Namespace defined in above mentioned file is - namespace yii\httpclient;

Now when I use this namespace in other file while setting up Google ReCaptcha

by writing "use yii\httpclient\Client"

then I am getting error "Class yii\httpclient\Client" not found

So I want to know whether namespaces are path dependent ? or is there a routing file or htaccess..etc where I can define the actual path of namespaces used in project, which YII2 compiler will refer to locate the file / class ?

Comment: You need to `include`/`require` the file, or set up autoloading for it…

Comment: PSR-4(https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) gives guidelines as to what you should do, but this isn't built into PHP.  This (as already pointed out) is the job that autoloaders are built to automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces themselves are not dependent on file path.

But you are probably mistaking what `use` clause does.

If you have this line in file:

```php
use yii\httpclient\Client;
```

It doesn't mean that the class is loaded. It only tells parser that you mean `yii\httpclient\Client` every time you use `Client` class in that file.

PHP has something called **autoload** to make sure you don't have manually `require` files for each class you are using. Autoloaders are called every time you are using some class if that class hasn't been loaded yet. When they are called they are given the class name and they check if they know how to load that class.

Now, even if the namespaces itself are not dependent on file path autoloaders usually uses those namespaces to decide where to look for the file containing that class.
And as **Nigel Ren** mentioned in comment, there exist [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) recommendation how to choose namespace and file structure to make sure that autoloader will know where to look for class.

Yii2 projects usually uses 2 autoloaders.
The Yii's own autoloader and autoloader generated by composer.

Since your question is about class that comes from `vendor\yiisoft\yii2-httpclient` the autoloader generated by composer.
If you check the [composer.json](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/3fc9b07b413ddddc4f74822b58df9b18f639f6f0/composer.json#L34) file in that package you can see that it has `autoloader` section with `psr-4` key. That tells composer that when it generates its autoloader it should be set to look for any class from `yii\httpclient` namespace in `src` folder of that package.

To make sure the composer's autoloader is working properly you have to go through following steps:
The `yiisoft\yii2-httpclient` package should be installed by composer.
If you need to regenerate composer's autoloader you can run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

The composer autoloader must be included in your application's entry point (usually `/web/index.php` or `/yii` files).
Check if those files have this line:

```
// in case of /web/index.php
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'); 

//in case of /yii
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```